# NSPopButton Stops NSTimer on main thread during selection

Tags: xcode, macos, nstimer, nsthread, nsbutton

I have multiple timers that working on the main thread.
And I have a NSPopButton. 
And I experience a bad behavior, timers just don't work, starting from the point that the use open the pop button's menu until he close the menu.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your NSTimer is running on the UI thread.
You should run it on another thread like so:

```
NSTimer *myTimer = …
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```